# How to install talib in win 11

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio

After reinstalling Python to 3.11. ver, I have tried multiple times to install TA-Lib for 64 bit. Commands !pip install talib, nor conda install TA-Lib, do not do it. Please show me how to install ta-lib. My current installation of talib is in C:Users\Name\anaconda3\site_packages. I am using VS Code.

Comment: There's no need to include your email address in your question.

Comment: Did you downgrade or upgrade your python version? I would always suggest using virtual environments instead of removing an installation of python.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/ provides several suggestions on how to install it, which are slightly different from the methods you quotes. I suggest cutting and pasting of the commands recommended there.

Answer (score 1):

According to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/),
Download [ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip) and unzip to C:\ta-lib.This is a 32-bit binary release.

**If you want to use 64-bit Python, you will need to build a 64-bit version of the library. Some unofficial (and unsupported) instructions for building on 64-bit Windows 10, here for reference:**

1. Download and Unzip `ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip`
2. Move the Unzipped Folder `ta-lib` to `C:\`
3. Download and Install Visual Studio Community (2015 or later) - Remember to Select `[Visual C++]` Feature
4. Build TA-Lib Library:
   From Windows Start Menu, Start `[VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt]`
   Move to `C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc`
   Build the Library `nmake`
   You might also try these [unofficial windows binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib) for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: Re-extracting the `.zip` file will help. Details see https://gist.github.com/mdalvi/e08115381992e42b43cad861dfe417d2?permalink_comment_id=4914347#gistcomment-4914347